# pyserial non-blocking __exit__

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I am writing to a serialport using pyserial (3.4) and its context manager. When a write_timeout occurs I want to close and exit without waiting for 30s. Is this possible?

```
with Serial(serialport, 115200, timeout=1, write_timeout=1) as serialhandler:
    while True:
        data = b'123'
        try:
            written = serialhandler.write(data)
        except Exception as error:
            log.error(error)
            break
log.debug('serial closed')  # takes 30s to reach here after write error has occured
```